# REST authentication for Android/iOS/Windows devices

Tags: rest, security, authentication, mobile, oauth

I'm creating a REST API that should have some quotas for clients. I'm using a very simple OAuth 2 mechanism where I use an authorization server to get a bearer token from a client ID and secret, and then I use the token until it expires.

The application has a user login where the user logs in with user and password and the app receives a new access token specific for the user, that can only be obtained again with a username and password.

The problem is that the Client ID and secret would have a quota of 10 requests per minute, for example, so that new developers can integrate the API in their services. So I can create a special ID with unlimited quota and set it as a constant in the code (which is a bad idea, decompiling it would lead to anybody being able to use the secret) or I could use some sort of per-device id and secret.

I was thinking on using Android Device ID (in the case of Android) to identify it, but how can I prevent somebody from creating a bunch of 64 bit numbers and trying to register with them? Is there any service to validate an Android Device ID? How would this be done in other platforms?

Is this the correct way to do it? should I change any part of the mechanism? How does Twitter do it? I know it has complete access to the API, while other developers require a client ID and secret.

Answer (score 0):

Any value that is solely generated on the client can be tampered with and should not be trusted. Even IP Addresses can be spoofed by simple applications.

With that said, have you considered [JWT's](https://jwt.io/) as a solution, basically you issue JWT's to clients these JWT's contain a unique identifier say UUIDv4 which identifies a client / user. This removes the case for forgery as you will be issuing the credentials.

At [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) we had a similar requirement to rate limit API calls to our endpoints on per tenant and per user / device basis we ended up writing [limitd](https://github.com/auth0/limitd). Its essentially a rate limit as a service solution which decouples the rate limiting logic from the application logic.

The system works by creating multiple buckets and then claiming tokens from each bucket this way we have implemented separate tenant, ip, user based restrictions.

Comment: And how do the clients ask for the token? What prevents other clients not using the official app from requesting those tokens?

Comment: User credentials, along with client ids. (If its running in a webview or is a webapp you can enforce CORS restrictions using Origin) but a native client will still be able to make a request.

Comment: But the thing is that when the native app sends a token request to the auth server, it will provide some HTTP headers. What would prevent another client from sending the same HTTP headers?